# Mostrar resultados filhos na array pai no Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Boa tarde, estou iniciando no Codeigniter e gostaria de uma ajuda.

Tenho uma tabela de Times de futebol. Cada time tem seus jogadores que estão em outra tabela do meu banco.

Recebo os valores destas duas tabelas separadas, mas gostaria de criar apenas uma array que organizasse cada time com seus respectivos jogadores.

Exemplo:

```
Times (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [time_name] => 'Barcelona'
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [time_name] => 'Real Madrid'
    )
 )

Jogadores (
    [0] => Array (
       [id] => 0
       [time_id] => 2
       [player_name] => 'Cristiano Ronaldo'
    )

    [1] => Array (
       [id] => 0
       [time_id] => 1
       [player_name] => 'Lionel Messi'
    )
```

Então eu gostaria de produzir uma array desta forma:

```
TimeCompleto (
    [0] => Array (
       [id] => 0
       [time_name] => 'Barcelona'
       Jogadores => Array (
           [1] => Array (
              [id] => 0
              [time_id] => 1
              [player_name] => 'Lionel Messi'
           )
       )
    )
```

Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elabore da seguinte forma:

```
public function lista_times_jogadores(){
    $consulta = $this->db->get('times')->result();
    foreach($consulta as &$valor){
        $this->db->where('time_id', $valor->time_id);
        $valor->jogadores = $this->db->get('jogadores')->result();
    }
    return $consulta;
}
```

Quando você usar a função junto ao método, ele retornará array com subarrays.

```
[0] => Array (
   [id] => 0
   [time_name] => 'Barcelona'
   Jogadores => Array (
       [1] => Array (
          [id] => 0
          [time_id] => 1
          [player_name] => 'Lionel Messi'
       )
   )
)
```